# Fabric.js blend image into background. blur at the edges

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I am trying to blend foreground image into background image using fabric.js
The foreground image should blur at the edges.

In the below example, dog is the foreground image.
scenery is the background image.

This is my code :

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setWidth(300);
canvas.setHeight(300);

canvas.setBackgroundImage('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/09/03/46/alberta-2297204__340.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
 
fabric.Image.fromURL('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/03/14/20/13/dog-287420__340.jpg', function(oImg) {
  canvas.add(oImg);

  canvas.item(0).set({        
 clipPath: new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 100, left:-90, top:-90
      })
  });
canvas.renderAll();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300" style="border:2px solid #000000"></canvas>
```

How to make the dog image blend into the background image (scenery) ?
The dog image should blur at the edges.

I want to do this using html5 canvas fabric.js (not using css).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of using clipath you could overlay a rectangle on top of the  image with a gradient fill . something like that(not tested):

```
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: /*same as the image*/,
    height: /*same as the image*/,
})

rect.setGradient('fill', {
  type: 'radial',
  colorStops: {
    0: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0)', 
    1: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 0)'
    2: 'rgba(255, 255, 0, 1)'
  }
});
```

Comment: maybe with fabric.Image.filters.GradientTransparency  http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Image.filters.GradientTransparency.html, or blendImage filter but i've never used filters so i can't be more precise

Answer (score -1):

You can actually do all this way easier with just css:

```css
.vignette-inset {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://fabricjs.com/assets/pug_small.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.vignette-inset:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 150px yellow;
}

/* removing shadow on hover
for demonstration purposes */
.vignette-inset:hover:after {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='vignette-inset' />
```

Comment: I want to be able to download the image later. so, I want to do it using html5 canvas fabric.js. thanks